# Will Google Images ignore images with empty alt text?

Tags: html, images, google-image-search

You can put images that are just decorative into a HTML document like this, by setting their alt text to nothing:

```html
<img src="decorative.png" alt="" />
```

This means that screen readers won't announce the image, and that if the image doesn't load, it won't show anything.

My question is, will Google Images ignore these images as well, and will it hide them in search results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> will Google Images ignore these images as well, and will it hide them in search results?

No, these images can still appear in Google Image Search.

If you specifically want to hide these images from Google Image Search then consider blocking them in `robots.txt`. Ideally, these images should be stored in a common location to make this task easier.

For example:

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /images/decoration/
```

Reference:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35308?hl=en